# Using Hangfire for automatic payment processing

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, owin, hangfire

I have just discovered hangfire. I have successfully installed the mysql storage version.  I want to use this in the following scenario:
Everyday at 12:01 am  it should  trigger an ASP.NET MVC5 with OWIN and EF application controller action that checks database and select  payment references due to be processed on  the date in question.  This action  ends by presenting an api url  to the payment processing provider.    My Question is  if my action is called  "ProcessPayments"  How do I set hangfire to repeat this process everyday.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone needs a start up push like myself when I asked this question.  Using Hangfire Mysql Storage,Identity 2,  ASP.NET, MVC5, EF, C# you could create  an action in your controller like below to add a recurrent job for the process.

```
public ActionResult PDPayment(int id)
{                     
string cronExp = "1 12 * * *";
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
var a = db.DDs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.DDId==id);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(a.id+"-"+a.DDId+"_job", () => ProcessPayments(id), cronExp);
return new EmptyResult();
}    
}
```

Then you create your method  or logic for the payment.

```
 public static void ProcessPayments(int id)
       {
   eg fetch records with id
   create invoice
   process invoice- payment
   update records of payment
   send email
   redirect to success or failed page     
       }
```